# Can't connect to MongoDB via flask_pymongo

Tags: flask, flask-pymongo

I just encountered a problem while playing with `Flask` and `MongoDB`. Here are scenarios

> With Authorization Enabled

If I use `PyMongo()` from `flask_pymongo` with `mongo = PyMongo(app)` pattern, I just get `Authorization Errors`. While I am able to successfully retrieve database via `MonogoClient()` from `pymongo` using same connection string.

> Without Authorization Enabled

If I use `flask_pymongo`, no errors. But I am not getting any data either. For example, `mongo.db.collection_names()` just returns empty array.  With `MongoClient()`, the same operation was successful.

> I am using:

- python = 3.6.3
- flask = 0.12.2
- flask_pymongo = 0.5.1
- pymongo = 3.5.1

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Here is the simple example of MongoDB with Flask https://stackoverflow.com/a/53998723/10849262

Comment: Here is the simple example of MongoDB with Flask https://stackoverflow.com/a/53998723/10849262

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Flask with Flask-PyMongo for a while now, and below is how I make my connections to a mongodb.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app) # very important!

USERNAME = '<username>'
PASSWORD = '<password>'
PORT = '27017'
HOST = 'localhost'

app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = '<DB Name>'
app.config['MONGO_HOST'] = HOST
app.config['MONGO_PORT'] = PORT
app.config['MONGO_USERNAME'] = USERNAME
app.config['MONGO_PASSWORD'] = PASSWORD
mongo = PyMongo(app)
```

You may not need the `CORS(app)` depending on your setup.

To create multiple connections do the following:

```
# Users db
app.config['MONGO2_DBNAME'] = 'users'
app.config['MONGO2_HOST'] = HOST
app.config['MONGO2_PORT'] = PORT
app.config['MONGO2_USERNAME'] = USERNAME
app.config['MONGO2_PASSWORD'] = PASSWORD
users_mongo = PyMongo(app, config_prefix='MONGO2')
```

I should also note that I had problems connecting with authorization through Flask-PyMongo because the database needed to have authorization configured a certain way.  Flask-PyMongo expects the db authority to be on the database itself and not elsewhere.  So when creating a user and password for a db do the following inside a mongo shell:

Create user admin

```
use admin
db.createUser({user: "userAdmin", pwd: "", roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ] } )
```

Create user on YOUR db

```
use <YOUR db>
db.createUser({user: "", pwd: "", roles:[{ role: "dbAdmin", db: ""}, {role: "readWrite", db: ""}]})
```

Within mongo and even with PyMongo you can create users within one database and give them access to other dbs, but Flask-PyMongo for whatever reason does not play nice here and you'll need the user created within the database you want to use.

Hope this helps as I've struggled here as well.  Feel free to ask for clarification